# How to access jenkinsfile local environment variables from post steps?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm attempting to add a post-build step to my jenkinsfile to apply a label to a build. The Jenkins variables are resolved fine, but the environment variables I've defined globally within the file are not resolved. Here's the relevant bits:

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    VERSION_MAJOR = '1'
    VERSION_MINOR = '0'
    VERSION_PATCH = '0'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        echo('Testing p4Tag')
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    success {
      build job: 'Copy-Installers',
        parameters: [
          // 
          string(name: 'MASTER_VERSION_MAJOR', value: '${VERSION_MAJOR}'),
          string(name: 'MASTER_VERSION_MINOR', value: '${VERSION_MINOR}'),
          string(name: 'MASTER_VERSION_FEATURE', value: '${VERSION_PATCH}'),
          string(name: 'MASTER_BUILD_NUMBER', value: '${BUILD_NUMBER}'),
          string(name: 'COMPONENT_NAME', value: 'Console')
    }
  }
}
```

The downstream build fails. Looking at the log it appears the local environment variables are not passed in:

```
The Build Number name is: ${VERSION_MAJOR}
The Build Number name is: ${VERSION_MINOR}
The Build Number name is: ${VERSION_PATCH}
The Build Number name is: 924
The Build environment name is: Console
```

**Update**

I've tried the following variations as well:

- `value: '${env.VERSION_MAJOR}'` - Fails similarly to above
- `value: '$VERSION_MAJOR'` - Fails similarly to above
- `value: $VERSION_MAJOR` - Fails with "no such property" error

**Update 2**

For what it's worth, these variables *can* be referenced from the `stage` section. For instance, this works as expected:

```
stage('build') {
  sh('./Build/build-package.sh $VERSION_MAJOR $VERSION_MINOR $VERSION_PATCH $BUILD_NUMBER')
}
```

Comment: You should probably not be passing variables as literal strings that cannot be interpolated. Additionally, you will probably also need to be accessing the values from the `env` map. Both of those will likely get you to success.

Comment: What makes a value "not interpolatable" (or put another way, how can I make these values interpolatable)? Also note that using the "env" map (see the update) does not work. Last, it's worth noting that these same values _can_ be referenced from `sh` scripts in the `stages` section.